# When using WiX, what should I supply for INSTALLDIR if I'm installing a Windows exe and a Web App?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My solution consists of a Web application, hosting a web service, and a Windows Forms client that communicates with that web service. The windows client is expected to run on the same machine as the web service, while remote clients access the web service via HTTP as per usual.

The installer I wish to write is to install the Web Application under `\InetPub\wwwroot\MyWebApp` while the Windows Forms client goes into `\Program Files\MyWindowsClient`.

I'm getting stumped on what to specify for the `INSTALLDIR` directory; I barely understand what its purpose is, given the presence of `TARGETDIR` (as a side note: why does the `Name` attribute of the `TARGETDIR` directory element have the value "`SourceDir`"? Convention? Magic value expected by Windows Installer?) My attempt at the WiX directory structure is:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <!-- Put stuff in Inetpub on the fattest drive.
       But what happens if user wants to override? -->
  <Directory Id="INETPUB" Name="Inetpub"> 
     <Directory Id="WwwRoot" Name="wwwroot">
       <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyWebService" />
     </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="??INSTALLDIR?? " Name="MyWindowsClient" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I guess my issue boils down to not understanding what the difference between the public properties `TARGETDIR` and `INSTALLDIR`, and whether or not I'm allowed to install two binaries in widely disparate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I do something like:

```
[ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product
[ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product\WebSite
```

I put the win app exe in the product folder and the IIS content under Website.  I'd then create another website and/or virtual directory in IIS and configure the document directory to point to the websites folder.

Comment: You're right of course: a web site doesn't _have_ to reside under \Inetpub\wwwroot. I'll probably go with this suggestion, and give administrators the option of overriding if they really do want to put it in \Inetpub\wwwroot.

Comment: And the way to do that is to use the ConfigurableDirectory attribute on the Feature element.  Done correctly, a custom setup dialog will show different paths when different features are selected.  You can then redirect as needed.   IIS configuration is tricky to capture in an installer because the installer is designed to keep it simple and automate while asking a minimum number of questions but in reality there are many many ways one could choose to configure it.  If a balance can't be found, then it's sometimes best to do IIS configuration after the install.